# Как вернуться к главной функции, после выполнения другой?

Tags: меню, c, функции

Здравствуйте, моя программа состоит из трёх функций: "main", "poPost" и "srVozr". Функция main отвечает за главное меню, poPost - отображает список поступивших пациентов в определённый день, srVozr - выводит средний возраст пациентов. Функции работают, но мне хотелось-бы, чтобы после выполнения одного из действий меню, с программой можно было снова работать.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<clocale>

struct ABONENT {
    char fio[21];
    int byear;
    int day;
    int mount;
    int year;
    char diagnoz[21];
};

void poPost(int k, ABONENT * tab);
void srVozr(int k, ABONENT * tab);

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    int i;
    FILE *f;
    struct ABONENT tab[300];
    if ((f = fopen("пациенты.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        puts("Файл не найден.");
    for (i = 0; !feof(f); i++) {
        fgets(tab[i].fio, 20, f);
        fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d", &tab[i].byear, &tab[i].day, &tab[i].mount, &tab[i].year);
        fgets(tab[i].diagnoz, 20, f);
    }
    int k = i; // номер последнего считанного элемента массива m
    //После выполнения poPost или srVozr нужно вернуться в это меню:
    puts("___________________________________________");
    puts("Выберите действие:");
    puts("1-для поиска пациентов по дню поступления");
    puts("2-для вывода среднего возраста пациентов");
    puts("Esc-выход");
    puts("___________________________________________");
    char c = getchar();
    switch (c) {
    case '1':
        poPost(k, tab);
        break;
    case '2':
        srVozr(k, tab);
        break;
    case '27':
        break;
    }
}

int poPost(int k, ABONENT * tab)
{
    bool est = 0;
    int dayC, mountC, yearC;
    puts("Ввод даты");
    puts("Введите день:");
    scanf("%d", &dayC);
    puts("Введите месяц:");
    scanf("%d", &mountC);
    puts("Введите год:");
    scanf("%d", &yearC);
    printf("%d.%d.%d:", dayC, mountC, yearC);
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++)
        if (dayC == tab[i].day && mountC == tab[i].mount && yearC == tab[i].year) {
            printf("\n %s %dг.р. %s", tab[i].fio, tab[i].byear, tab[i].diagnoz);
            est = 1;
        }
    if (est == 0)
        puts("Ни один из пациентов не приехал в этот день");
    getch();
}

void srVozr(int k, ABONENT * tab)
{
    int vozrast = 0, obVozrast = 0, srVozrast;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        vozrast = 2012 - tab[i].byear;
        obVozrast = obVozrast + vozrast;
    }
    srVozrast = obVozrast / (k);
    printf("\n Средний возраст пациентов - %d лет", srVozrast);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: @AlexC: переместил, спасибо!

Comment: @AlexC, а программа-то точно работает? Судя по тому, что происходит с getchar() и не должна вообще :-)

Comment: @VladD,точно, только на бесконечно цикле while(c='1'), если ставлю while(c!='27'), то программа сразу завершается. Работает,и возвращение к стартовому меню, но завершить цикл через ESC не могу(

Comment: @AlexC: попробуйте тогда `do { ... } while (c != 27);` (Переменную `c` придётся заказать повыше.) Обратите внимание, что `case '27'` неправильно: надо `case 27:`.

Comment: Ещё раз внимательно посмотрите на прототп функции getchar(), и подумайте что с чем вы сравниваете в while() и в case. Подсказка: getchar() возвращает int, а не char. И какой код символа '1', а какой - у '27'...

Comment: @klopp: странно, что '27' вообще скомпилировалось, это ж не один символ.

Comment: В сях это допустимо - двухсимвольные константы преобразуются в int. Но всё равно ничего хорошего из этого не получается :-)

Comment: @klopp: правда? не знал, спасибо.

Comment: do{
              system("cls");
           puts("___________________________________________");
           puts("Выберите действие:");
           puts("1-для поиска пациентов по дню поступления");
           puts("2-для вывода среднего возраста пациентов");
           puts("___________________________________________");
          scanf("%d",&c);
               switch(c){
          case 1: poPost(k,tab); break;
          case 2: srVozr(k,tab); break;}
         }while(c=!4);
        }

Comment: Хочу заметить, что в стандартной виндовской CMD ESC (код 27) просто не вводится 

(в getchar() не попадает, куда девается не знаю).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте цикл `while` вокруг вывода `меню/getchar/switch`.

---

Обновление:

У меня вот такое работает:

```
char c;
bool selectionValid = true;
do
{
    if (selectionValid)
    {
        puts("___________________________________________");
        puts("1-search");
        puts("2-output");
        puts("3-exit");
        puts("___________________________________________");
    }
    c = getchar();
    selectionValid = true;
    switch (c) {
    case '1':
        puts("\n\nperforming search\n\n\n");
        break;
    case '2':
        puts("\n\nperforming output\n\n\n");
        break;
    case '3':
        break;
    default:
        selectionValid = false;
        break;
    }
}
while (c != '3');
```

Надо, однако, после каждого ввода нажимать на Enter.

Comment: @AlexC: а с `do {} while` вышло?

Comment: Сейчас как раз так и стоит, но не сильно помогает.(

Comment: @VladD, ещё раз спасибо за помощь) Добавил в case '3': return 0; и заработал выход)

Comment: @AlexC: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Решение в принципе плохое. 
Для работы с меню надо обрабатывать коды нажатых клавиш управления (стрелки, Enter и т. д), а не вывод на экран. Тогда меню всегда будет сохраняться на экране и не будет проблем с вызовом подпрограмм. Очень подробно это описано в методичке Чернова Э. А. на сайте кафедры МАДИ: МАДИ.ru -> Кафедры -> Автоматизированных систем управления->Методические и учебные пособия-> Чернов Э.А->Методические указания к курсовой работе по СПО. Там же описано, как правильно переключать кодировку длоя русского языка.

Comment: @Lookbar: не-а, `getchar` не должен доставлять стрелки и тому подобное. Если пользоваться системно-зависимыми сторонними библиотеками, программа не будет переносима.